# PHP wrapping arrays with a parent array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a structure as below:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
      array (size=2)
        0 => string
        1 => string

array (size=2)
  0 => 
      array (size=2)
        0 => string
        1 => string
  1 => 
      array (size=2)
        0 => string
        1 => string
```

What I want to do is wrapping this arrays with a "parent" array like I show below:

```
array
 0=> array (size=1)
      0 => 
          array (size=2)
            0 => string
            1 => string

 1=>  array (size=2)
        0 => 
           array (size=2)
            0 => string
            1 => string
        1 => 
            array (size=2)
             0 => string
             1 => string
```

How can I achieve this?

Thank you!

**EDIT**

```
$__server_description_path_data = explode('}', $data);

    foreach ($__server_description_path_data as $value) {
        $_server_description_path_data[] = trim($value, '{HEX');
    }

    foreach ($_server_description_path_data as $value) {
        $server_description_path_data[] = explode(":", $value);
    }
```

The snippet above gives me structure like 1st part (array) of the question. What I'd like to do is getting a structure as in my second part of my question.

**EDIT2**

```
array
  0=> array
       0=> array
          0=> string
          1=> string
array
  0=> array
      0=> array
          0=> string
```

Comment: Unless you provide the code you've created for the original structure, it looks like you've already achieved your goal... :)

Comment: @summea okay I am editing the question by providing codes

Answer (score 0):

presuming your top code shows two var_dumps, i have called the arrays array1 & array2:

```
$parent=array($array1, $array2);
```

EDIT so `var_dump($server_description_path_data);` provides the top output?
if so how about:

```
$wrapper= array($server_description_path_data);
var_dump($wrapper);
```

Comment: when I var_dump I got a structure like in first part of the question. What I'd like to do is when I var_dump, getting a structure like in second (wrapped with an parent array) part of the question.

Comment: @curiozity edited my answer, though im not sure how you could have got the top output with the code you provided

Comment: I tried that one what it does is getting each array and giving a "0" index to each of them. 

Like: Please have a look at EDIT2.
 
Yet, I'd like to achieve is getting an ONE parent array which wraps ONE level down ARRAYS with INCREASING index values just like in second output part of my question. Could you help me about this?

Answer (score 0):

```
$new_big_array = array($old_array1, $old_array2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array1 = array(1,2,3);
$array2 = array(3,4,5);
$array3 = array($array1, $array2);
```